# Average Memory Usage Query - Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

How do I write a query that outputs average memory usage for instances over the past 24 hours?
The following query displays the current memory usage

```
100 * (1 - ((node_memory_MemFree + node_memory_Cached + node_memory_Buffers) / node_memory_MemTotal))
```

For CPU, I was able to use irate

```
100 * (1 - avg(irate(node_cpu[24h])) BY (instance))
```

How do I use irate and avg for memory?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> average memory usage for instances over the past 24 hours

You can use `avg_over_time`:

```
100 * (1 - ((avg_over_time(node_memory_MemFree[24h]) + avg_over_time(node_memory_Cached[24h]) + avg_over_time(node_memory_Buffers[24h])) / avg_over_time(node_memory_MemTotal[24h])))
```

> For CPU, I was able to use irate

`irate` only looks at the last two samples, and that query is the inverse of how many modes you have and will be constant (it's always 0.1 on my kernel). You want

```
100 - (avg by (instance) (rate(node_cpu{job="node",mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100)
```

Note that this is a 5 minute moving average and you can change `[5m]` to whatever period of time you are looking for such as `[24h]`.

Answer (score 18):

Update commands

**CPU Usage :**

```
(1 - avg(irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[10m])) by (instance)) * 100
```

**Memory Usage :**

```
100 * (1 - ((avg_over_time(node_memory_MemFree_bytes[10m]) + avg_over_time(node_memory_Cached_bytes[10m]) + avg_over_time(node_memory_Buffers_bytes[10m])) / avg_over_time(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes[10m])))
```

Comment: Your Memory Usage query shows percentage of Memory Available, not percentage of Memory Usage. To get the "Memory Usage" you need to delete the `-1`.

Answer (score 10):

Also, we can query with accounts;

**CPU Usage for Windows**

```
#Average
100 - (avg by (instance) (irate(windows_cpu_time_total{job=~"dev",mode="idle"}[2m])) * 100)
#Minimum
100 - (max by (instance) (irate(windows_cpu_time_total{job=~"dev",mode="idle"}[2m])) * 100)
#Maximum
100 - (min by (instance) (irate(windows_cpu_time_total{job=~"dev",mode="idle"}[2m])) * 100)
```

**CPU Usage for Linux**

```
#Average
100 - (avg by (instance) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job="$job",mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100)
#Minimum
100 - (max by (instance) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job="$job",mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100)
#Maximum
100 - (min by (instance) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job="$job",mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100)
```

**Memory Usage for Windows**

```
#Average
100.0 - 100 * avg_over_time(windows_os_physical_memory_free_bytes{job=~"prod"}[30d]) / avg_over_time(windows_cs_physical_memory_bytes{job=~"prod"}[30d])
#Maximum
100.0 - 100 * min_over_time(windows_os_physical_memory_free_bytes{job=~"prod"}[30d]) / min_over_time(windows_cs_physical_memory_bytes{job=~"prod"}[30d])
#Minimum
100.0 - 100 * max_over_time(windows_os_physical_memory_free_bytes{job=~"prod"}[30d]) / max_over_time(windows_cs_physical_memory_bytes{job=~"prod"}[30d])
```

**Memory Usage for Linux**

```
#Avarege:
100 * (1 - ((avg_over_time(node_memory_MemFree_bytes{job=~"prod"}[30d]) + avg_over_time(node_memory_Cached_bytes{job=~"prod"}[30d]) + avg_over_time(node_memory_Buffers_bytes{job=~"prod"}[30d])) / avg_over_time(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{job=~"prod"}[30d])))

#Maximum:
100 * (1 - ((min_over_time(node_memory_MemFree_bytes{job=~"prod"}[30d]) + min_over_time(node_memory_Cached_bytes{job=~"prod"}[30d]) + min_over_time(node_memory_Buffers_bytes{job=~"prod"}[30d])) / min_over_time(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{job=~"prod"}[30d])))

#Minimum
100 * (1 - ((max_over_time(node_memory_MemFree_bytes{job=~"prod"}[30d]) + max_over_time(node_memory_Cached_bytes{job=~"prod"}[30d]) + max_over_time(node_memory_Buffers_bytes{job=~"prod"}[30d])) / max_over_time(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{job=~"prod"}[30d])))
```

Note:- {job=~"prod"}, is account name. you can use your account names

Answer (score 3):

In newer versions you probably add `_bytes` in all queries, like the examples above